# vb.net 4 threads to fill the same database

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

Hello i've a loop that last about 2 hours to finish, it gets the data from internet and fills it to a database so i want to divide it to 4 threads, and i am trying to do some testing before i put this to my application.

so here is a sample that i wrote to fill one database by 4 threads 
and i am getting this error "BindingSource cannot be its own data source"

```
  Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = Me.bindingSource1
    GetData("select * from products")
End Sub

 Public Sub thread1f0()
    For i = 0 To 500
        DataGridView1.Item("PD", i).Value = i + 67
        DataGridView1.Item("PDP", i).Value = i + 41
        DataGridView1.Item("TPD", i).Value = i + 654 + 6 * 13
        DataGridView1.Item("TPDP", i).Value = i + 342
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub thread1f1()
    For i = 501 To 1000
        DataGridView1.Item("PD", i).Value = i + 432
        DataGridView1.Item("PDP", i).Value = i + 421
        DataGridView1.Item("TPD", i).Value = i + 414
        DataGridView1.Item("TPDP", i).Value = i + 42 + 4
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub thread1f2()
    For i = 1001 To 1500
        DataGridView1.Item("PD", i).Value = i + 4452
        DataGridView1.Item("PDP", i).Value = i + 34
        DataGridView1.Item("TPD", i).Value = i + 123
        DataGridView1.Item("TPDP", i).Value = i + 44
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub thread1f3()
    For i = 1501 To 2000
        DataGridView1.Item("PD", i).Value = i + 423
        DataGridView1.Item("PDP", i).Value = i + 423
        DataGridView1.Item("TPD", i).Value = i + 423
        DataGridView1.Item("TPDP", i).Value = i + 423 / 2
    Next

End Sub
```

'//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    thread0 = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf thread1f0)
    thread0.Start()

    thread1 = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf thread1f1)
    thread1.Start()

    thread2 = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf thread1f2)
    thread2.Start()

    thread3 = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf thread1f3)
    thread3.Start()
End Sub



Public Sub GetData(ByVal selectCommand As String)

    Try
        Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFileName
        Me.dataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(selectCommand, connectionString)
        Dim commandBuilder As New OleDbCommandBuilder(Me.dataAdapter)
        Dim table As New DataTable()
        table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
        Me.dataAdapter.Fill(table)
        Me.bindingSource1.DataSource = table
        Me.DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns( _
            DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.ColumnHeader)
    Catch ex As OleDbException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you think that using threads will help? Chances are that IO is the bottleneck, and adding threads will not help with that.

Comment: well it might not help, but i just want to learn how to use them so i wonder why is that exception generated

Comment: I would say that the error has nothing to do with threading. How are you binding your data? Are you binding a control to itself?

Comment: i've added the code to the question, did some reasearch on google and its seems to be about cross threading but i wonder how it can be fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your DataGridView control is using a DataTable as a DataSource, you need to update the DataTable, not the DataGridView control.

The threads don't seem necessary.  Just use one BackgroundWorker thread to not freeze the GUI.

Comment: ok first error is gone but now i am getting "DataTable internal index is corrupted"!

Comment: @user1570048 That's because of your threads.  You have four threads trying to update a single thing at the same time.  Hence why Oded commented that "adding threads will not help with that".

Comment: so there is no solution?, what if each thread has its own connection

Comment: @user1570048 To what problem?  Threads don't make things faster.

Comment: i know it depends on io ram and internet speed!, but simply is there a way to make the above code work as it should, 4 threads same time same database

Comment: i am not sure how can assign different datatable to each thread

Comment: @user1570048 Have you profiled your application?  What is the problem you are trying to solve?  You seem determined to use threads but you seem to ignore the help that says threads won't make this faster.  The link I gave you also showed you how to lock the table so that each thread has a chance to update the table, which would solve the corrupted index issue.

Comment: well basicly i am new to programming and just trying to learn how to use threads :)

Comment: @user1570048 That's good to learn.  It's also important to learn "when" to use threads.  Having four threads updating a DataGridView probably isn't it.

Comment: what if that datagrid had 5 million records?

Comment: i am studying economics so i might see such database :D and i am determined to make the above code work

Comment: ok i manged to do it but i am having a problem!..i have 4 binding sources but how do i add all of them to the same datagrid?

Comment: @user1570048 That's obviously not going to work.  When each thread goes to update the DataTable, you need to lock the table.  This will block the other threads from updating until the table is available again.  As you can see, this will actually slow things down.

Comment: what i am thinking of is let threads do their work when they are done update data grid